# Kubernetes: Can not telnet to ClusterIP Service inside my Cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I want to deploy Jenkins on a local Kubernetes cluster (no cloud).
I will create 2 services above Jenkins. 
One service of type NodePort for port `8080` (be mapped on random port and I can access it outside the cluster. I can also access it inside the cluster by using `ClusterIP:8080`). All fine.

My second service is so my Jenkins slaves can connect.
I choose for a ClusterIP (default) as type of my service:

I read about the 3 types of services:

- clusterIP:

> Exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value
>   makes the service only reachable from within the cluster.

- NodePort: is not necessary for 50000 to expose outside cluster
- Loadbalancer: I'm not working in the cloud

Here is my `.yml` to create the services:

```
  kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: jenkins-ui
    namespace: ci
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
      app: master
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
        name: master
---
  kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: jenkins-discovery
    namespace: ci
  spec:
    #type: ClusterIP
    selector:
      app: jenkins
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 50000
        targetPort: 50000
        name: slaves
```

The problem is that my slaves can not connect to port 50000.
I tried to telnet the `ClusterIP:port` of the service jenkins-discovery and I got a connection refused. I can telnet to `ClusterIP:port` of the jenkins-ui service. What am I doing wrong or is there a part I don't understand?

Comment: Assuming you've got the DNS add-on enabled, what does, from within the cluster, `curl jenkins-discovery.default.svc.cluster.local` give you?

Comment: i know you said "no cloud", but maybe you would figure out what is going wrong by trying https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-on-kubernetes? or this non-cloud walk-through: https://blog.kublr.com/using-jenkins-and-kubernetes-for-continuous-integration-and-delivery-4e4341aff013

Comment: Can you check `kubectl get ep jenkins-ui -n ci` ? Could it be a problem with your `selector` or a maybe a `readinessProbe` you have on the Jenkins master?

Comment: @JanosLenart the output of your command is: `jenkins-ui   10.42.120.179:8080   1d`. For discovery it has Endpoints <none> where jenkins-UI has serviceIP:Port

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas I'm pretty new to this. I don't know if it's enabled. The curl does not work inside my cluster. I can curl https://kubernetes.default.svc.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. The mistake was the selector which is a part which wasn't that clear for me. I was using different nodeselectors what seemed to cause this issue. This worked:

```
 kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: jenkins-ui
    namespace: ci
  spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
      app: master
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 8080
        targetPort: 8080
        name: master
---
  kind: Service
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: jenkins-discovery
    namespace: ci
  spec:
    #type: ClusterIP
    selector:
      app: master
    ports:
      - protocol: TCP
        port: 50000
        targetPort: 50000
        name: slaves
```